# Access on remotely of mysql

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, permissions

I want to acces mysql server on my system in sql yog.but it is giving me error of

```
access denied for user root @ 192.168.2.4 to database database name
```

what can i do to solve this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check the users table in mySQL and ensure that there is a valid entry there for root@192.168.2.4.

There normally will be an entry for root but the hostname would be localhost which will not 
allow root@192.168.2.4 to connect.

If you want to access the system as root from this ip address you need to make 192.168.2.4 a valid host for the root user or use wildcard % which would allow you to connect from any ip address (not recommended).

The best solution would be to configure SQLYog to use root@localhost when connecting to you local system. I haven't used SQLYog so I am not really sure how to go about doing this.

Look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) for the reference on adding users in mySQL.

Comment: I have one entry in db table of host:192.168.2.4,db:mydb,user:root,all priviliages yes except gran priveilages no. and in users table i have one entry of this Host : 192.168.2.4 user root , all privilages yes except grant privl

Comment: still i am not able to connect through sql yog